# trouble sending modal form contents to PHP file with AJAX and Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to learn how to submit form data to a PHP file from a bootstrap modal. From the other questions I've seen, I thought I had it right, but I keep getting the error dialog. I must be missing something obvious.

**test.php**

```
<html>  
   <body>
  <div class="container padding-top-10 change-width">    
    <div class="row padding-top-20" align="center">
      <button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bandModal">Add Band(s)</button>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div id="thanks"></div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="bandModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content modal-lg">
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="bandModalLabel">
                    Add a Show
                </h4>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal Body -->
        <div class="modal-body row">

          <div class="container col-md-12">
            <form id="addBandForm">
              <h3>Band Details<small>Enter each band name and primary contact information...</small></h3>
              <div class="well" id="newBandRows">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for "newBandName">Band Name:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newBandName" name="newBandName" placeholder="Enter Band Name" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="primaryContact">Primary Contact:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="primaryContact" name="primaryContact" placeholder="Enter Name" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for "personEmail">Primary Email:</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="primaryEmail" name="primaryEmail" placeholder="Enter Email" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for "personPhone">Primary Phone #:</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="primaryPhone" name="primaryPhone" placeholder="Enter Phone #" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="newRowButton">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-1">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-left" onClick="addNewBandRow();">+</button>
                  </div>
                  <div id="remover" class="col-md-1">

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-7">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3 padding-top-10">
                    <button id="addBandSubmit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <script src="js/newBand.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            </form>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

**Jquery**

```
             $(function() {
    //twitter bootstrap script
    $("#addBandSubmit").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "womhScripts/addBand.php",
        data: $('#addBandForm').serialize(),
        success: function(msg) {
          $("#thanks").html(msg)
          $("#bandModal").modal('hide');
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) { var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")"); alert(err.Message); }
      });
    });
  });
```

**addBand.php**

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['newBandName'])) {
$bandName = strip_tags($_POST['newBandName']);
$contact = strip_tags($_POST['primaryContact']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['primaryEmail']);
$phone = strip_tags($_POST['primaryPhone']);

echo "bandName      =".$bandName."</br>"; 
echo "contact       =".$contact."</br>"; 
echo "email     =".$email."</br>"; 
echo "phone     =".$phone."</br>"; 
echo "<span class="label label-info" >your message has been submitted .. Thanks you</span>";
}?>
```

Comment: look at your developer console, see if there's anything in there

Comment: Plus look at these `$contact` - `$primaryContact` and other variables there. Error reporting should be throwing you undefined variables notices and is failing on you silently because of it.

Comment: what error you get? From what you say I understand ajax requests returns an error.Are you posting in the correct path???You can try error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
  alert(err.Message);
} and tells us what the error actually is.

Comment: What happened when are click on button?

Comment: I hung around this question long enough. Pay me by the minute/hour and I'll stay here all day if you want. You've been comments; read them and understand them. I'm out.

Comment: i updated the jquery to report errors, but it doesn't seem to be reporting any errors. I also updated the variables in the PHP file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through your code and found quite a few errors.

In your test.php change the Submit button from a button to an actual submit button.

```
  <input id="addBandSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</input>
```

In your Jquery 
Add the preventDefault() function to stop the form from submitting to the same page.

```
     $("#addBandForm").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
         url: "womhScripts/addBand.php",
         type: "POST",
         data: $('#addBandForm').serialize(),
         success: function(msg) {
           $("#thanks").html(msg);
           $("#bandModal").modal('hide');
         },
         error:function(errMsg) {
           console.log(errMsg);
        }
       });
     });
```

You can read about what the preventDefault function here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

In your addBand.php change the double quotes around your label label-info to single quotes. You cannot have double/single quotes inside double/single quotes inside php.

```
echo "<span class='label label-info' >your message has been submitted .. Thanks you</span>";
```

Also it helps to use the console to see exactly what is being posted using the Network tab in Chrome or Firefox .

Please mark this as the answer if it works for you. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea about the console in chrome... again, thank you. Also, I didn't have the button type set cause I didn't know about the prevent default method... Do you have a recommendation on what I could read to learn about other commonly used methods that I should know about?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to implement. You can always look through code on Stack or Github. There are plenty of open source libraries with great code for a variety of purposes. Happy coding.